# PostgreSQL connection accepted without providing SSL certificates

Tags: postgresql, linux, postgresql-11, ssl, certificate

Hopefully someone might be able to shed a light on this problem.

I've configured two servers, both of them have the same problem.

I've implemented SSL configuration, on PostgreSQL 11.18, I have created self-signed certificates, configured the **postgresql.conf** file with

```
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
```

On the **pg_hba.conf** file I've added

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
hostssl    demo        user_test       10.155.5.100/32      md5 clientcert=verify-full
```

For the client, I've created certificates with the **CN=user_test** defined, and I can connect with

```
psql "sslmode=verify-full sslcert=/location/user.crt sslkey=/location/user.key 
sslrootcert=/location/root.crt host=10.5.1.57 dbname=demo user=user_test"
```

After I run the command on the client server, it asks for the password and it connects properly.
I see the legend

```
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
```

and I can confirm I am connected on the desired server, as I can see the expected databases.

**The problem is** that I can also run on the client server

```
psql -d demo -U user_test -h 10.5.1.57
```

it will ask for the password, and it connects.

The desired behaviour is to **only** allow connection if the certificates are provided.

- I'm making the connection between two Linux servers.
- All of the entries with the same user or ip in the **pg_hba.conf** are registered with **hostssl** and **md5 clientcert=verify-full**
- My **server.crt** and therefore my **root.crt** is defined with CN=10.5.1.57
- The server should still be able to accept other user connections
  without providing certificates.

Thanks a lot, I appreciate any help or hints on what might be wrong.

Comment: 1. A rule that you **add** to pg_hba.conf is ignored when other rules above it do match. This is an IF...ELSIF...ELSIF cascade. It's not apparent what are the other rules in your file. 2. Set `log_connections` to `on` and consult the server log file to troubleshoot.

Comment: _The server should still be able to accept other user connections without providing certificates_ -- perhaps that's the source of your problems, if you added the `clientcert=verify-full` after those other lines. Also, what's the purpose of asking for the password when using the certificate-based authentication?

Comment: @DanielVérité
In my pg_hba.conf I have these lines at the begining 

`# local for Unix domain socket connections only

local   all             all                                     trust

local   all             postgres                                trust

# IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all                     127.0.0.1/32            md5

host    all             postgres                127.0.0.1/32            password
`

And several others for connections for other users and ips, not related to this client server and all of them without ssl connection.

Comment: @DanielVérité following that line of thought, I added the line at the very beginning of the pg_hba.conf file, but I still get the same behaviour.

Comment: @mustaccio I did try several other ways on the pg_hba.conf file in order to not request the password, and only authenticate through the certificates, but it didn't work. Any combination I tried, kept asking also for the password.

Comment: @DanielVérité I did turn on log_conections after you mentioned it, but in both cases (with or without certificates) I see the same 
LOG:  connection authorized: user=user_test  database=demo SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.2, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256, compression=off)

Comment: You should hit the [edit link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/321047/edit) on your question to add all the relevant information to it.

Comment: When you put that line first in the pg_hba, change the auth method to "reject".  This will quickly give you definitive evidence whether it is hitting the line you think it is.